# Bayes law $ \mathbb{P}(Y\geq3|X=1) $ with dice and choosing balls

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Assume there are 3 balls in a box, two of them have the digit $1$ printed and the other one has digit $2$ printed.

Let $ X $ be a random variable that denotes which ball was chosen.(uniform probability)

If $X=1$ we roll a dice until we get an even result.

Else we roll a dice until we get 6.
Let $ Y $ be the amount of dice rolls required.

Calculate $$ \mathbb{P}(Y\geq3|X=1) $$

Basically we need $$ \frac{\mathbb{P}\left(Y\ge3\cap X=1\right)}{\mathbb{P}\left(X=1\right)} $$
How do I solve this using Bayes law, or how can I apply the $\mathbb{P}(A)=1-\mathbb{P}(A^C)$?

What I wanted to do is $$ \frac{1-\mathbb{P}\left(Y=2\cap X=1\right)-\mathbb{P}\left(Y=1\cap X=1\right)}{\mathbb{P}\left(X=1\right)} $$
This is wrong because $$ \left(Y\ge3\cap X=1\right)^{C}=\left(\left(Y=anything\cap X=2\right)\cup\left(Y=1\cap X=1\right)\cup\left(Y=2\cap X=1\right)\right) $$
But then I would need to work hard for $X=2$ so I figured that the whole $X=1$ experiment has probability $\frac{2}{3} $ So I can just calculate $$ \frac{\mathbb{P}\left(Y\ge3\cap X=1\right)}{\mathbb{P}\left(X=1\right)}=\frac{\mathbb{P}\left(X=1\right)-\mathbb{P}\left(Y=2\cap X=1\right)-\mathbb{P}\left(Y=1\cap X=1\right)}{\mathbb{P}\left(X=1\right)} $$
Why does it work out like that?Is there a way to solve this with known formulas?

Comment: If $X = 1,$ you roll a dice until you get an even result. That means that on the event $\{X = 1\},$ the random variable $Y$ is geometric with success probability $\dfrac{1}{2}$ ("even result"). That means $P(Y \geq 3 \mid X = 1) = \sum\limits_{k =3}^\infty (\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{2})^{k-1} = \frac{1}{4}.$

Comment: I found the same result but I think calculating a series is a bit of an overkill considering we only need to find $\mathbb{P}\left(Y=2\cap X=1\right)-\mathbb{P}\left(Y=1\cap X=1\right) $, if this was a tougher series\ then I would have to work the the complement as I did, but I just can't figure out why it works out that why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z_1, Z_2, Z_3, \ldots$ be the sequence of rolls (i.e. $Z_i$ is the number of the $i$th roll).  Then

$$P(Y \geq 3 \mid X=1) = P(Z_1 \text{ and } Z_2 \text{ are both odd } \mid X=1),$$

since all the $Z_i$ are independent of $X$,
$$P(Z_1 \text{ and } Z_2 \text{ are both odd } \mid X=1) = P(Z_1 \text{ and } Z_2 \text{ are both odd}),$$

and since $Z_1, Z_2$ are independent,
$$P(Z_1 \text{ and } Z_2 \text{ are both odd}) = P(Z_1 \text{ is odd})\cdot P(Z_2 \text{ is odd}).$$

That is,
$$P(Y \geq 3 \mid X=1) = P(Z_1\text{ is odd})\cdot P(Z_2\text{ is odd}) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$$